# WebGL and rectangular (power of two) textures

Tags: opengl-es, textures, webgl

WebGL is known to have [poor support for NPOT (non-power-of-two) textures](http://www.khronos.org/webgl/wiki/WebGL_and_OpenGL_Differences#Non-Power_of_Two_Texture_Support). But what about rectangular textures where both width and height are powers of two?  Specifically, I'm trying to draw to a rectangular framebuffer as part of a render-to-texture scheme to generate some UI elements.  The framebuffer would need to be 512x64 or thereabouts.

How much less efficient would this be in terms of drawing? If framerate is a concern, would I do better to allocate a 512x512 power-of-two-sized buffer and only render to the top 64 pixels, sacrificing memory for speed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There has never been the constraint for that width must equal height.

Comment: To develop a little more on this answer: some Compressed texture extensions *require* that the textures be equal width and height (WebGL still doesn't support them), but that's not a restriction nor a performance hit to standard OpenGL/WebGL behavior.

Answer (score 2):

More specifically: 2D textures are not at all required to be square; a 512x64 texture is not only allowed but should also be efficiently implemented by the driver; on the other hand cube maps need to be square.

For 2D textures, you can use NPOT textures if both wrap modes are CLAMP_TO_EDGE and your minification filter does not require a mipmap. Efficiency of NPOT texture may vary depending on your driver.